# Group by date range on weeks/months interval

Tags: mysql, sql, date, group-by

I'm using MySQL and I have the following table:

```
| clicks | int  |
|   period  | date |
```

I want to be able to generate reports like this, where periods are done in the last 4 weeks:

```
|   period    | clicks |
|  1/7 - 7/5  |  1000  | 
| 25/6 - 31/7 |  ....  |
| 18/6 - 24/6 |  ....  |
| 12/6 - 18/6 |  ....  |
```

or in the last 3 months:

```
| period | clicks |
|  July  |  ....  |
|  June  |  ....  |
| April  |  ....  |
```

Any ideas how to make select queries that can generate the equivalent date range and clicks count?

Comment: Your storing your date as an int? How does that field look?

Comment: @simendsjo  Confusing Formatting - I thought the same but read across not down!

Comment: sorry for that mistake, it's a filed called period with date type.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
SELECT
 WEEKOFYEAR(`date`) AS period,
 SUM(clicks) AS clicks
FROM `tablename`
WHERE `date` >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 4 WEEK
GROUP BY period

SELECT
 MONTH(`date`) AS period,
 SUM(clicks) AS clicks
FROM `tablename`
WHERE `date` >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH
GROUP BY period
```

Comment: That's a better check for the period, I corrected my answer to reflect it.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how the queries should be if the period field is an integer like 20100609 which corresponds to 2010-06-09 date. Would the performance be better in such int type?

Comment: Probably only if you need to filter a range of dates because you can't filter by week (you still have to cast it as a date).
And remember to choose an answer :P

Comment: @khell: I wouldn't bother with such micro-optimalizations. I've done this a thousand times on large tables without any problems. Just make sure you are indexing the column.

Comment: I'm wondering if there is a way to the display the periods for the weekly report as mentioned in the question

Comment: I'll add that if you're going to be grouping on a function like `WEEKOFYEAR(date)`, you may also want to group by `YEAR(date)` because otherwise week 3 2015 and week 3 2016 would be grouped into a single data point (week 3), which may not be your expected behavior.

Comment: @simendsjo - how can we use date range `where date >= staringdate and date <= endingdate - interval 3 month` ?

Answer (score 3):

For the last 3 months you can use:

```
SELECT MONTH(PERIOD), SUM(CLICKS)
FROM TABLE
WHERE PERIOD >= NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH
GROUP BY MONTH(PERIOD)
```

or for the last 4 weeks:

```
SELECT WEEK(PERIOD), SUM(CLICKS)
FROM TABLE
WHERE PERIOD >= NOW() - INTERVAL 4 WEEK
GROUP BY WEEK(PERIOD)
```

Code not tested.

Comment: I don't know if the optimizer works with WEEK(Period) without checking all the dates in the result. That's why I like to use WEEK(Period) AS WeekPeriod, Group by WeekPeriod

Comment: I use mainly Oracle for which you have to group by the same field you select (you can't alias a field and group by that).
I think internally the query is the same.