# Dynamically Create/Select Rows of Dates in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Using the following nested `SELECT ... UNION SELECT ...` query I can return rows of Month/Year for the last 6 months (including the current month)

```
SELECT month_year
FROM
  (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%M %Y') as month_year
   UNION
   SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH),'%M %Y')
   UNION
   SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH),'%M %Y')
   UNION
   SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH),'%M %Y')
   UNION
   SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 4 MONTH),'%M %Y')
   UNION
   SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 MONTH),'%M %Y')
    ) a
```

results in-

```
month_year
April 2015
March 2015
February 2015
January 2015
December 2014
November 2014
```

Is it possible to recreate this query so that is created dynamically, namely not have to add/remove `UNION SELECT ...` to get more/less Month/Year rows?

Clearly the following query won't work, but is there some way to do something like-

```
SELECT month_year
FROM
  (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`thisDate`,'%M %Y') as month_year WHERE `thisDate` BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 MONTH) LIMIT 6
  ) a
```

where I only have to change the `INTERVAL 5` and `LIMIT 6` integers to change the number of rows returned.

---

**Application**

If I have a table `sales` and each row is the amount sold on that day.

```
date          amount
2015-01-03    100
2015-01-10    50
2015-03-07    75
2015-03-14    60
2015-03-21    40
...
2014-10-31    125
```

Now I want to get the totals per month, for the last 6 months. If I do a standard query, using a `LIMIT 6`

```
SELECT
   DATE_FORMAT(date,'%M %Y') as month_year, SUM(amount)
FROM
   sales
GROUP BY
   month_year
LIMIT 6
```

I will end up with `October 2014` as there is no rows from `April 2015` OR `February 2015`.

So my thinking is to create a 'temporary' table of rows of date, and then `LEFT JOIN` my `sales` query -

```
SELECT a.month_year, b.amount
FROM
  (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%M %Y') as month_year
   UNION
   SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH),'%M %Y')
   UNION
   SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH),'%M %Y')
   UNION
   SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH),'%M %Y')
   UNION
   SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 4 MONTH),'%M %Y')
   UNION
   SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 MONTH),'%M %Y')
  ) a
LEFT JOIN 
  (SELECT
       DATE_FORMAT(date,'%M %Y') as month_year, SUM(amount)
   FROM
       sales
   GROUP BY
       month_year
   ) b
 ON b.month_year = a.month_year
```

But, if I want to change the months to 7,8,9 or 3,4,5 I will have to add/remove rows, where I would like to be able to just change 1 or 2 integers.

Comment: Could you speak a bit more to your usage?  I mean, it would be simple to do a group on a date field, and using MySQL to generate a bunch of months without additional data would be somewhat ridiculous, so this is a question that may be answered better with more context.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/while.html

Comment: @JohnGreen I have updated my question with the application of the query.

Comment: Ah, so you have gaps, caused by the GROUP BY that you're trying to avoid.  Are you making a view?  This would be trivial with dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use this

You can set how old is the search by changing "INTERVAL XX MONTH".

Downside is: If you end up with a month without sales, that month will not be present in the query result.

```
SELECT
MONTH(`date`) AS period,
SUM(ammount) AS clicks
FROM `sales`
WHERE `date` >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 10 MONTH
GROUP BY period
```

Credits: [Group by date range on weeks/months interval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012895/group-by-date-range-on-weeks-months-interval)

Comment: Your 'Downside' is the issue. I want that last 6 months, concurrently, even if the month returns a NULL or 0 amount.